# Haskell with OpenGL. (Unknown GLUT entry glutInit)

Tags: haskell, opengl, glut

I need help getting OpenGL and GLUT to work using Haskell.

Running a windows 10 system.
I have installed the OpenGL package using `cabal`, but when I try to run the following program (and similar tutorial-like short programs):

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop

display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
  clear [ ColorBuffer ]
  flush
```

All I get is:

```
main: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)
```

I have looked around for solutions but come up empty handed.

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered same problem and found the [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/31kb85/having_trouble_getting_gloss_to_install_on_windows/).

Use [this](http://files.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MinGW.zip)([source](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)). Copy `freeglut/bin/(platform)/freeglut.dll` to your executable path and rename it to `glut32.dll`.

Comment: Actually I also faced the same problem. I was not able to know where the dll file was to be copied. So, what I did was :                                
                            sudo apt-get install haskell-platform                                     The glutInit function is provided by freeglut(as mentioned in the answer) which is installed using the above command.