# Windows 10, Haskell GLUT library -> Main.hs: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)

Tags: haskell, glut, freeglut

I'm getting an error after running a script from example

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop
 
display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
  clear [ ColorBuffer ]
  flush
```

I already downloaded and copied freeglut.dll as glut32.dll into C:\Windows\SysWOW64, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072958/haskell-with-opengl-unknown-glut-entry-glutinit - Try to follow the answer there, just copy the dll into your project folder.

Comment: I've already seen this question. glut32.dll and Main.hs should be in the same folder. The error doesn't disappear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get Freeglut to work with Haskell on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956387/cant-get-freeglut-to-work-with-haskell-on-windows)

Comment: If you want a new answer to and old question, consider setting a bounty on it.